# error: expected ‘)’ before ... (header file constructor)

Tags: c++11

I have this header file for a class Dictionary

```
#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

class Dictionary {
public:
    Dictionary(string wordFile);
    bool contains(const string& word) const;
    vector<string> get_suggestions(const string& word) const;
private:
    unordered_set<string> words;
};

#endif
```

and I'm getting the error "error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token Dictionary::Dictionary(string wordFile) ". In the .cpp file it looks like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "word.h"
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

Dictionary::Dictionary(string wordFile) {
  string str;
  ifstream input(wordFile);

  while (getline(input, str)) {
    words.insert(str);
  }
}

bool Dictionary::contains(const string& word) const {
  unordered_set<string>::const_iterator got = words.find(word);
  if(got == words.end()){
    return false;
  }
  return true; 
}

vector<string> Dictionary::get_suggestions(const string& word) const {
  vector<string> suggestions;
  return suggestions;
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong... I come from a Java background and I'm having some trouble getting accustomed to writing in C++ and fixing these errors.

Comment: Is that the only error you get? Do you use `using namespace std;`?

Comment: I'm not using namespace std, however I edited my code and added the scope "std::" everywhere in my header file, and now I get only this error in my .cpp file:   error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 Dictionary::Dictionary(string wordFile) {

Comment: `#include "Dictionary.h"`?

Comment: edited so you can see the whole .cpp file, and yes I am including the header file

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, assuming you've added `std::` in *all* the right places. Could it be a stray bracket in `word.h`?

Comment: You need to also go through the .cpp file and scope things with `std::`

Comment: To get a hint if it's a problem with a header, I'd recommend to move the `include` it around. If the error moves, it's most probably a problem with a header. Or make a simple program using only `word.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original error was because you didn't qualify `string` in the header file:

```
   Dictionary(string wordFile);
```

That should be:

```
Dictionary(std::string wordFile);
```

(and similarly for the other uses of `string` and `unordered_map` in the header).

You'll have the same problem in the .cpp file, but you can solve it there by simply adding `using namespace std;` to the top of the file, **after** all the `#include` directives. (You should not put `using namespace` in header files, or before including headers files, as it can have unwanted consequences and confuse later headers).

Comment: doing all this solved the problem it seems. I assumed it was enough to include string, unordered_set, etc... but I had to add namespace as well. Silly...
Thanks a lot!